# Error on PloneFormGen 1.7.17

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, ploneformgen

I encountered problems when I added Products.PloneFormGen 1.7.17 in Plone 4.3.7

**Run buildout**

I got the message below as an error.

```
jamie@ubuntu01:~/Plone/zinstance$ bin/buildout
While:
  Initializing.
  Getting section buildout.
  Initializing section buildout.
  Getting option buildout:backups-dir.
Error: Referenced option does not exist: buildout var-dir
```

**Plone error**

After I clicked the submit, I got the message below as an error.

```
 Traceback (innermost last):
    -Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
    -Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    -Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
    -Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in        
  __call__
    -Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 26, in _call
    -Module Products.CMFFormController.FormController, line 384, in validate
    -Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    -Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
    -Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerValidator, line 58, in __call__
    -Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
    -Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
    -Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
    -Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
    -Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
    -Module script, line 41, in fgvalidate_base
<FSControllerValidator at /copy2_of_rwdSR1/0413-test/fgvalidate_base>
Line 41
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 585, in fgvalidate
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 633, in   fgProcessActionAdapters
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 524, in onSuccess
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 945, in send_form
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 635, in get_mail_text
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 905, in get_header_body_tuple
    -Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 787, in secure_header_line
    -AttributeError: find
```

Please tell me how to fix it, thank you.

Comment: The buildout warning is totally unrelated with your PFG error: ignore it.
Please provide some details about your mail adapter configuration (a screenshot about how it's configured) and you Plone mail host settings

Comment: Going by the line numbers, you're doing something odd with the reply-to address of the mails you want to generate. (Are you getting it out of something that's not an unformatted textfield?)